# react native how to link official libraries (like CameraRoll)?

Tags: react-native

I've tryed to install camera roll with the official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html).
But i couldn't find the name of the library in npm
I've tryed :

```
npm install RCTCameraRoll --save
```

but i get

```
npm ERR! code E404
```

what is the proper way to do it ?
NOTE: i don't want to install a third party plugin i want to use facebook CameraRoll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its part of the react-native api as [mentionned](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html) in the docs so you dont need to save it as dependency from NPM.

So you just do :

```
import React, { CameraRoll } from 'react-native'
```

Take a look at the example from the docs, it's quite complete.

Comment: That was it thanks. But why do they say "Before using this you must link the RCTCameraRoll library. You can refer to Linking for help" ?

Comment: Because when you use libraries that requires native modules like (CameraRoll) You need to link them and make them available for calling inside javascript. Certain NPM packages also require you to do this in order for them to work. I won't go into details, but essentially they are implemented in native code and need to be made available to your javascript via the RCT Bridge.

Comment: Ha ok ! Didn't understand it that way thanks a lot :)

Comment: My pleasure :) Feel free to contact me if you have any questions on react or react-native.

Comment: @WilomGfx do you know if the CameraRoll is working on Android ?  I tried to use the exmaple from docs, but it's not working...

Comment: define not working ? as far as i know it works on android.

Answer (score 19):

Inorder to use CameraRoll in ios you need to:

1. Drag the node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll/RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj file in your Libraries folder in Xcode
2. in Xcode Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries -> then press + sign and add the libRCTCameraRoll.a
3. Recompile your app

Comment: on react 61.5 you dont need to do this.